# как сохранить состояние кнопки отдельной ячейки tableView в UserDefaults

Tags: swift, tableview, nsuserdefaults

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в ячейке кнопка изменила свое изображение, а при повторном запуске приложения изображение этой кнопки оставалось измененным. У меня при изменении кнопки в одной ячейке, при перезапуске приложения изменяются изображения кнопок всех ячеек таблицы.
вот код cellForRowAt :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CoverCell", for: indexPath) as! CoverTableViewCell
   let cover = presenter.covers?[indexPath.row]
    cell.coverNameLabel?.text = cover?.title
    guard let url = URL(string: presenter.covers?[indexPath.row].image ?? "") else { return cell }
    cell.coverImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: nil)

    let favoriteButton = UIButton(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35))
    favoriteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    favoriteButton.tag = indexPath.row
    favoriteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "star"), for: .normal)
    favoriteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "blackStar"), for: .selected)
    favoriteButton.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSaved")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    cell.accessoryView = favoriteButton
    return cell
}
```

а вот функция нажатой кнопки:

```
@objc func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isSelected, forKey: "isSaved")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    if sender.isSelected {
        guard let covers = presenter.covers else { return }
        FavoriteCovers.favoriteCovers.append(covers[sender.tag] )
    }
    
}
```

Буду признателен за помощь, думал что возможно нужно сделать массив кнопок, но не смог реализовать это. Занимаюсь всего пару месяцев, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Если набор данных остается неизменным и в таблицу не добавляются новые записи, то проще всего сохранять массив выбранных индексов

```
class FavoriteCovers {
    
    // ...
    static var coverIdentifiers: [Int]!
    
}
```

Читаем при загрузке приложения

```
FavoriteCovers.coverIdentifiers = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "coverIdentifiers") as? [Int] ?? []
tableView.reloadData()
```

В методе `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` восстанавливаем выбор

```
favoriteButton.isSelected = FavoriteCovers.coverIdentifiers.contains(indexPath.row)
```

Сохраняем выбранные кнопки

```
    @objc func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected.toggle()
        
        guard let covers = presenter.covers else {
            return
        }
        
        if sender.isSelected {
            FavoriteCovers.favoriteCovers.append(covers[sender.tag])
            FavoriteCovers.coverIdentifiers.append(sender.tag)
        } else {
            // сравниваем заголовки, также можно добавить другие условия для идентификации
            FavoriteCovers.favoriteCovers.removeAll { $0.title == covers[sender.tag].title }
            FavoriteCovers.coverIdentifiers.removeAll { $0 == sender.tag }
        }
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(FavoriteCovers.coverIndices, forKey: "coverIdentifiers")
    }
```

**Вариант 2**

Если скажем при загрузке приложения список может измениться (удалили или добавили записи во внешнем источнике, откуда они грузятся), то индексы для сохранения использовать не получится, так как они сместятся. В этом случае нужен какой-то другой уникальный идентификатор для записей, например сочетание `title` + `image`. Тогда можно сделать так

```
struct Cover {
    
    var title: String?
    var image: String?
    var identifier: String {
        (title?.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString() ?? "") + (image?.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString() ?? "")
    }
}

//...

FavoriteCovers.coverIdentifiers = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "coverIdentifiers") ?? []

//...

favoriteButton.isSelected = FavoriteCovers.coverIdentifiers.contains(presenter.covers?[indexPath.row].identifier ?? "")

//...

        if sender.isSelected {
            FavoriteCovers.favoriteCovers.append(cover)
            FavoriteCovers.coverIdentifiers.append(cover.identifier)
        } else {
            // сравниваем заголовки, также можно добавить другие условия для идентификации
            FavoriteCovers.favoriteCovers.removeAll { $0.title == cover.title }
            FavoriteCovers.coverIdentifiers.removeAll { $0 == cover.identifier }
        }
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Помогло

Comment: @maksim2302 в таком случае примите ответ, поставив возле него галку